# What is use of old cricket ball?

Tags: cricket, equipment

When umpire change the cricket ball, was the old ball thrown as waste or keep for reuse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends - there's a number of possibilities:

- Someone keeps it as a souvenir (10/5-wicket haul)
- It's re-used
  as a replacement ball in another match
- It's passed on to the nets for
  use there
- It's discarded

It all depends on the match, the events during it and the state of the ball itself.

Answer (score -1):

It completely depends :

1. If any bowler takes 10/5-wicket haul thn they keep that bowl with them as memory.
2. Other reason is completely depends on ball condition.

   I. Ball is stored by ICC rules to replace it for some overs in other international event.

   II. If ball condition is not good enough to play thn ball is discarded.